# Mint 16 - Won't boot to USB

Tags: linux-mint, boot, uefi

I am attempting to completely remove my Linux Mint 16 MATE OS and reinstall Windows 8. At which point, I'll decide if I want to reinstall a Linux OS (most likely will). **The issue I'm having is that my computer won't boot to USB,** even though I've set USB as the very first option in the BIOS UI.

I'm wondering if the fact that I've got a UEFI bootloader has anything to do with it... **I've disabled fast-boot and secure-boot options.**

Any idea what might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to disabling fast-boot and secure-boot, you must:

- Use the USB 2.0 port (lest Drivers be installed for USB 3.0)
- Disable UEFI boot-mode - In my case, the **legacy** boot mode was a CSM
  option